# VLC command line convert

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

I've worked out how to convert wavs to mp3s via VLC using the command line tool in WinXP.

```
'vlc "C:\temp\Britney Spears - California Uber Alles.wav" :no-video :sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=256}:std{access=file,mux=dummy,dst="c:\temp\Britney Spears - California Uber Alles.mp3"} vlc://quit'
```

Is there a way that I can substitute the filename, like %1, so that the output name is named the same as the input name (with the exception of the extension, obviously). 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, I may not have the double quotes perfect for every case, but you can customize it as you want it. And note that %~1 would remove quotes whereas %1 would keep quotes. And you can add quotes within the batch file too, perhaps around a %~1 or wherever you want.

you can remove the echo lines too, they're just to demonstrate to you the concept of %~dnp1

The key is  %~dpn1  rather than %1

Here is an example of a bat file called a.bat and you would call

```
C:\>a.bat "C:\temp\Britney Spears - California Uber Alles.wav"
```

Notice there are two invocations of vlc, one shows your one, the other shows with %1 or %~dpn1

I included both just to demonstrate it so you see the two.

do call /?  to see variations of %1 e.g. how I found out about %~dpn1

```
echo %1
echo %~dnp1
echo a.bat blah.wav

vlc "C:\temp\Britney Spears - California Uber Alles.wav" :no-video :sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=256}:std{access=file,mux=dummy,dst="c:\temp\Britney Spears - California Uber Alles.mp3"} vlc://quit


vlc %1 :no-video :sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=256}:std{access=file,mux=dummy,dst="%~dnp1.mp3"} vlc://quit
```